# Using multiple conditions in onBackPressed() Android

Tags: android, webview, floating-action-button

I'm using a very simple app with a WebView and an Extended Floating Action Button.

On the press of back button by the user, I want 3 different things to happen at different times:

- If Extended FAB is visible, hide it
- If Extended FAB isn't visible and(&&) WebView is not on the first index of BackForwardList(meaning if the user is not on the homepage of the app), go back(meaning go to the previous page until the user reaches the homepage of the app)
- If WebView is at an index smaller than the first index of BackForwardList(meaning if the user is on the homepage itself) and(&&) FAB isn't visible, show a message to exit out of the application

**The Issue**

First 2 functions are working fine, the third one, isn't working, i.e. if I click on the back button when I'm already on the homepage and(&&) the FABs are closed as well, it doesn't show up the message "Do you want to exit?"

What am I doing wrong?

Here's my MainActivity

```
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {

        WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);

        if (areAllFabsVisible ) {

            hideFabs();

        }

        if ( myWebView.copyBackForwardList().getCurrentIndex() > 0 && !areAllFabsVisible) {
            myWebView.goBack();
        }



        else if (myWebView.copyBackForwardList().getCurrentIndex() < 0 && !areAllFabsVisible) {

            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            builder.setCancelable(false);
            builder.setMessage("Do you want to Exit?");
            builder.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    //if user pressed "yes", then he is allowed to exit from application
                    finish();
                }
            });
            builder.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    //if user select "No", just cancel this dialog and continue with app
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            });
            AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
            alert.show();
        }


        
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is here:

```
 else if (myWebView.copyBackForwardList().getCurrentIndex() < 0 && !areAllFabsVisible) {
```

The indices of the BackForwardList() can't be negative, so you should write it like:

```
 else if (myWebView.copyBackForwardList().getCurrentIndex() == 0 && !areAllFabsVisible) {
```

to check if you're on the first page. That means you're at the 0th index meaning your homepage.